# Loop my button clicks in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, button

These are 4 buttons I have on my webpage below is the code:

```
<div id ="topbar" width="80%; height:20px;" style="text-align:center">
    <input type="button" value="Click first" onclick="button.toggle();"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Click second" onclick="button2.toggle();"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Click third" onclick="button3.toggle();"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Click fourth" onclick="button4.toggle();"></input>
</div>
```

Currently when page is loaded, all of them are "on" (toggle does On or Off)
How do I turn them all off, and then loop them like this:

1 on rest off
2 on rest off
3 on rest off
4 on rest off
1 on rest off.... and it keeps looping.

I have tried this approach 
Whats wrong with this?

```
setInterval ( "loop()", 2000 );

function loop ( )
{
setTimeout ( "SetLayer1()", 1000 );
}

function SetLayer1()
{
button.toggle(); //all off since all of them are on from start
button2.toggle();
button3.toggle();
button4.toggle();
}
function SetLayer2()

button.toggle(); // button 1 on rest off
//button2.toggle();
//button3.toggle();
//button4.toggle();
}
function SetLayer3()
{
button.toggle(); // button 1 off
button2.toggle(); //button 2 on
//button3.toggle();
//button4.toggle();
}
function SetLayer4()
{
//button.toggle();
button2.toggle();// button 2 off
button3.toggle();// button 3 on
//button4.toggle();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, its not as easy... :) I am trying indenting..... 4 spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's elementary, Watson. Recursion. An example implementation can be like this:

Make a variable holding all of your buttons and another variable called `index` (or something like that.) Then, make a function.

Inside that function, you do a check. If there is a `buttons[index]` (index is not larger or smaller than the length of all your button's array), make `index=0`. Then, toggle `buttons[index]` and increment `index`.

You then call `setTimeout` - the first parameter being the name of the function, the second one being the amount of time you want to wait before firing it.

Once outside of the function, call `setTimeout` in the same manner.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bVNx2/

Comment: Your example link disables the buttons one by one, I want to simulate clickings.

Comment: @Ossi Oh, then what did you mean by `.toggle`? I thought you meant disable/enable, because `toggle` doesn't exist on elements. With slight altering, your desired effect can be achieved - open your console and see http://jsfiddle.net/bVNx2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this approach, I think it may meet your need:

http://trendmedia.com/news/infinite-rotating-images-using-jquery-javascript/